# Return the stack element at a given index without modifying the original Stack in Java

Tags: java, reference, stack

Ok I was recently asked this in an interview, and I am intrigued. Basically I have a stack with a certain set of values, I want to pass the stack object in a function and return the value at certain index. The catch here is that after the function is complete, I need the stack unmodified; which is tricky because Java passes reference by value for objects. I am curious if there is purely a java way to do using `push()`, `pop()`, `peek()`, `isempty()` and primitive data type. I am against copying the elements into an array or string. Currently the cleanest I have got is using clone, find the code below:

```
    import java.util.Stack;


public class helloWorld {

public int getStackElement( Stack<Integer> stack, int index ){
    int foundValue=null;//save the value that needs to be returned
    int position=0; //counter to match the index
    Stack<Integer> altStack = (Stack<Integer>) stack.clone();//the clone of the original stack
    while(position<index)
    {
        System.out.println(altStack.pop());
        position++;
    }
    foundValue=altStack.peek();
    return foundValue;
}

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.push(10);
        stack.push(20);
        stack.push(30);
        stack.push(40);
        stack.push(50);
        stack.push(60);
        helloWorld obj= new helloWorld();
            System.out.println("value is-"+obj.getStackElement(stack,4));
        System.out.println("stack is "+stack);

    }

}
```

I understand that cloning is also copying, but that's the basic flaw I am aiming to remove. Stripped down I am asking if I would be actually be able to pass the stack's value instead of passing the value of its reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java Stack class extends Vector, so you can just get the element by index.

Comment: @nhahtdh: In real-life, one would do that. I wonder if that is what the interviewer was aiming for, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh That was my first reaction but as I said, or rather the guy told me just to use push, pop and isempty and primitive data types. any ideas?

Comment: @Punkeshwar: Just use another stack, and push/pop over to the next stack until you reach the element, then push/pop again to restore the stack.

Comment: @nhahtdh Agreed that those are the first few thoughts that come into someone's mind. But I think the solution provided by THILO is closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cannot use another stack, you can cheat and abuse a local variable on the call stack for the same purpose by making a recursive method:

```
public static <T> T getStackElement(Stack<T> stack, int index) {
  if (index == 0) {
    return stack.peek();
  }

  T x = stack.pop();
  try {
    return getStackElement(stack, index - 1);
  } finally {
    stack.push(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, i think we can cheat a bit, given that he is going to own me in the prospective future. I think this should work...Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
int position =5;

Integer result = stack.get(position);
```

Java Doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get%28int%29)

Comment: I have to wonder if that is considered cheating. Usually a stack does not have this operation (I know the Java one does).

Comment: Also, I think you got the indexing wrong. Should be the 5th-last element of the Vector, I think (if position=1 means top of the stack).

Comment: You are right, position 0 means bottom stack. (I just choose a random number in my answer)

Comment: Yes, but get(0) gets the *bottom* element of the stack (not the top one).

Comment: Similar to what provided by nhahtdh, and yes usually Stack do not have this operation.