# How can I look at a specific item in a stack?

Tags: java, stack

I've has a look around and can't seem to fins an answer.

In Java, if I have a stack with 10 items, is there a way to look at the 4th item without altering the stack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking stacks don't offer index based access, but depending on the implementation there may be a way. Of course if you find yourself observing the inner contents of a stack, it may not be the correct datatype for you.

Comment: The answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507978/return-the-stack-element-at-a-given-index-without-modifying-the-original-stack-i

Comment: What kind of stack? If it's a `java.util.Stack`, then yes. Could you post some code as a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to see element at specific index in Java's `java.util.Stack`:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

// adding multiple elements to stack

stack.elementAt(3);
```

Reason for this is because Stack is extending `Vector` and elementAt is Vectors method... Also, Vector has the following public method:

```
stack.get(3);
```

So this will work too...

And Vector is basically wrapping array, so it will work in `O(1)`.

This of course, goes against theoretical Stack, but most of data structures in Java are different, they mostly wrap basic array so you end up having more functionalities...